# Dynamically create and update json using bash

Tags: json, bash

In my hypothetical folder `/hd/log/`, I have 2 dozens Folder and each folder has log files in this format `foldername.2017.07.09.log`. I have a crontab that gzips the last log file every night, so there is a new log file with new log name every day.

I am trying to create a dynamic json file whose out put looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Foldername": "foldername", 
        "lastmodifiedfile": "/hd/log/foldername/foldername.2017.07.09.log"
    }, 
    {
        "Foldername": "foldername2", 
        "lastmodifiedfile": "/hd/log/foldername2/foldername2.2017.07.09.log"
    }
]
```

The bash script should be able to dynamically create array for each subfolder name (in case more folder are added or names are changed) and also give direct link to the last modified file.

I already php program to parse json file, but no sane way to crease this json file dynamically.

Any help or pointers is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your efforts.

Comment: *Strongly* recommend you use `jq` and not bash to manipulate json objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "%s" "["
for var in $(find /hd/log -type d)    
do
   path=$("ls -1t $var" | head -1)
   echo $var"/"$path | awk -F\/ '{ printf "%s","\n\t{\n\t\t\"Foldername\":\""$(NF-1)"\",\n\t\tlastmodifiedfile\":\""$0"\"\n\t},"}'
done
printf "%s" "]"
```

Here we find all directories in /hd/log in a loop taking each directory in turn and then using ls -1t | head -1 to get the last modified file in the directory. The path and file is then parsed through awk to get the desired output. We first set the delimiter for awk as / with the -F flag. Then we then print the json syntax as required using the last but one / delimited piece of data for the directory (NF -1 - number field -1) and the complete line for the last modified file ($0).

Comment: It almost worked. The only thing I wanted but didn't list the last modified log file for that folder, it listed all files in that folder. I am not familiar with bash that well so not sure where would I begin to try to fix this.

Comment: OK, I've amended the solution. I think it may be more in line with what you require now.